# Why my function in register_uninstall_hook from WP doesn't delete tables

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code in my WP plugin:

```
if (class_exists('mypluginname')) {
    $mypluginname = new mypluginname;
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array($mypluginname, 'activation'));
    register_uninstall_hook( __FILE__, array($mypluginname, 'uninstall'));
}
```

And I have this function in class:

```
function uninstall() {

    if (!defined('WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN')) {
        die;
    }

    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$wpdb->prefix}my_x");
    $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$wpdb->prefix}my_y");
    $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$wpdb->prefix}my_z");

}
```

If I uninstall my plugin, tables in DB are not deleted. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Your class method "uninstall" must be a static class method! https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_uninstall_hook/

Try it like this!?

```
class mypluginname{
    static function uninstall() {
        if (!defined('WP_UNINSTALL_PLUGIN')) {
            die;
        }

        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$wpdb->prefix}my_x");
        $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$wpdb->prefix}my_y");
        $wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$wpdb->prefix}my_z");
    }
}

if (class_exists('mypluginname')) {
    register_uninstall_hook( __FILE__, 'mypluginname::uninstall' );
}
```